# Angular: how can I order ng-repeat by array order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

### Problem

Is there a way to instruct Angular to order an `ng-repeat` by the repeat's source data *order*?

If not, how else can I use `ng-repeat`'s `orderBy` within the context of a container directive? Details on my use-case are below.

---

### Info

I have a situation where a directive wraps an arbitrary list of items. Specifically, the data bound to the ng-repeat is a subarray of longer list. In my particular case, I have a directive that wraps another directive that utilizes `ng-repeat`. E.g.,

```
<generic-list-container>
    <youtube-item ng-repeat="video in vm.videos"></youtube-item>
</generic-list-container>
```

Now suppose that `generic-list-container` has some specific rules on ordering its child list, and that it can accept any child list (within reason, of course).

In such a case, I probably don't want to use `| orderBy:` , at least as I understand it, because it leaves the ordering logic up to some controller other than `generic-list-container`'s controller. To clarify, the template for `generic-list-container` does *not* have an ng-repeat, because that reduces the generality of the directive. Rather, the ng-repeat is in the *page* template, where the directive is actually used.

I actually have logic for the ordering I want in the directive's controller logic, but **I'm not sure how to give angular that information**.

Ideally, there would be a way where I can tell Angular to order by the array order, or the array index, but I'm not sure how to do that in this context.

### Sample Code

Heads up, I'm posting this to give you a taste of what I'm going for, it's not the full picture, but I don't think the full-picture is necessary for the code.

```
  function slider() {

    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      transclude: true,
      templateUrl: 'my-template.html',
      controller: 'SliderCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: {
        show: '@',
        index: '@',
        scrollBy: '@'
      },
      scope: {},
      link: linkFunc
    };

    function linkFunc($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl, $transclude) {

      if (angular.isUndefined(ctrl.show)) {
        ctrl.show = 4;
      } else {
        ctrl.show = Math.abs(ctrl.show);
      }

      if (angular.isUndefined(ctrl.index)) {
        ctrl.index = 48;
      } else {
        ctrl.index = Math.abs(ctrl.index);
      }

      if (angular.isUndefined(ctrl.scrollBy)) {
        ctrl.scrollBy = 1;
      } else {
        ctrl.scrollBy = Math.abs(ctrl.scrollBy);
      }

      //wait for ng-repeat to be ready
      var unbind = $scope.$watch('vm.ready', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal === true) {

          // active is a subarray of ctrl.items
          ctrl.active = [];

          //find subarray start, end indexes

          var start = ctrl.index + ctrl.show;
          var len = ctrl.items.length;

          //add items to the subarray
          for (var i = ctrl.index; i < start; i++) {
            ctrl.items[i%len].slide.active = true;
            ctrl.active.push(ctrl.items[i % len]);
          }

          //sort the sub array???
          if (start >= len) {
            ctrl.active.sort(function (a, b) {
              return b.index - a.index;
            });
          }

          unbind();
        }
      });

    }
```

Comment: If you omit the `orderBy`, the `ng-repeat` should go in array order, which seems to be what you want.  Is that not working for you? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @DanielBeck You are understanding me correctly. The devil's in the details though; the array I'm using in the ng-repeat is a subarray of the array indexed by Angular. I'm using `ng-if` to hide array elements not contained in the subarray. The source array's ordering isn't the same as the subarray's.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to create a [custom angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter). It is dead simple to do so.

Create a filter like this:

```
.filter('sortArray', function() {
  return function(array, sortOrder) {
    return array.sort(...add some function here that sorts on sortOrder);
  };
})
```

Then you can use the filter like this:

```
<generic-list-container>
    <youtube-item ng-repeat="video in vm.videos | sortArray : vm.sortKind"></youtube-item>
</generic-list-container>
```

Where `vm.sortKind` is a scope variable that you can define.

Comment: My question is: can I define `sortKind` on the `generic-list-controller` scope? It's scope is isolated by design. If I can't do this, then the `orderBy` solution doesn't work, because it ties my directive to a controller other than the directive's controller.

Comment: Yes, you can. `sortKind` can be replaced by any angular expression. Maybe that was misleading to prefix `sortKind` with `vm`.

Comment: Thanks. How would I use the sort without an `ng-repeat`? I don't want to force `ng-repeat` children.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Are you looking to avoid using ng-repeat in your html? Or are you looking to have the array sorted and filtered before hitting the ng-repeat? If the former, then you should sort and filter in JS. If the latter, then I recommend against it. Using a filter on ng-repeat is more efficient than applying a $watch on a larger array and then ng-repeat on the sub-array. Angular was specifically designed to handle filters on large arrays efficiently.

Comment: Neither. The array should be sorted *after* `ng-repeat`.

Comment: So, you want the items to appear sorted in the UI? That is what the filter does.

Comment: SO's unhappy about all the comments, so this will be my last. Answer: filter operates on the raw list provided to the `ng-repeat` directive - but I *don't* want to do that. I want to operate on a subarray. Apologies for the inarticulate question, I'm not great with phrasing the problem. See my solution for a better approach. And yes, I do mean better; I experimented with filters and they were not what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to the problem I described was to hide the transcluded, `ng-repeat`'d list, and in the directive template, use a custom transclude directive to render the subarray. Details are below.

## Big hat tip to the [Angular UIB](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js#L236) project for providing the idea.

#### Example `generic-list-container` template:

```
<div class="generic-list-container">
    <div class="generic-list-container-content">
        <ol class="generic-list-container-list">
             <!-- render the subarray... -->
            <li ng-repeat="item in subarray" class="generic-list-item">
                <div generic-list-container-transclude="item">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <!-- ...and hide the full list -->
        <ol class="generic-list-container-hidden" style="display: none;" ng-transclude>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Example `generic-list-container-transclude` directive:

```
  function genericListContainerTransclude() {

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '^genericListContainer',
      link: linkFunc
    };

    function linkFunc($scope, $element, $attrs) {

      var item = $scope.$eval($attrs.genericListContainerTransclude).item;

      item.$transcludeFn(item.$parent, function (contents) {
        angular.forEach(contents, function (node) {
          $element.append(node);
        });
      });

    }

  }
```

#### Final note: wrap the `ng-repeat`'d item in a directive, and include the following line its directive definition:

```
  $scope.$transcludeFn = transclude;
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but this seems significantly more complex than just implementing a filter (remember that a filter can filter, sort, and otherwise manipulate its input as it gets transformed to output).

Comment: My initial post got an important detail wrong. Data was bound to the full `ng-repeat` list. Now it's just the subarray. The subarray has special ordering rules, not the source array. If I order the source array differently, it interferes with the subarray indexing. By transcluding just the active items, I can slim down the view and apply special ordering on only the affected items, leaving the source indexing - which is important for reference - unadulterated.

Comment: I still don't understand. With the filter, you can remove all but the appropriate sub-array, and then sort on that. This will not affect the underlying data, but only the view on that. In effect, there would not be any sub-array declared in JavaScript. Rather the sub-array would be generated by the filter during digest cycles.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I'm not sure whether it fits my circumstance well. At this point, a plunkr would be helpful.

Comment: If I get some time in the next bit, I'll throw one together.

Comment: Something like this, both filters and sorts the array before displaying it: http://plnkr.co/edit/15WyT1z1adCqAYXCacrn?p=preview If you need to start using transclusions for something like this, then I'd think there's something wrong with your design.

Comment: Thanks. The plunker doesn't capture many of the details of my use case though. I think the UI-Bootstrap team's approach is best. I'll try to get a plunker together at some point to illustrate why I need transclusion.